# Dragging an object using perspective camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a function so when I hold the mouse down I can drag the game object and then I latch it into target.
I'm using a perspective,vertical camera with physical Camera checked and with focal length 35. Also I don't know if this is important but I am dragging the object in the Y and Z axis.
The code I'm using drags the objects too close to the camera. How can I fix this?

```
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    if (IsLatched)
    {
        print($"is latched:{IsLatched}");
        return;
    }
    float distance = -Camera.main.transform.position.z + this.transform.position.z;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 rayPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
    this.transform.position = rayPoint;
    print($"{name} transform.position:{transform.position}");
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
    isHeld = true;
}
```

Comment: Use Physics.Raycast so you get the hit position from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the distance by subtracting the z coordinates, then taking a point along the click-ray with that distance. That will not be a point on the same z coordinate. If you want to keep one component constant, I would rather intersect the ray with an XY plane.

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
float Zplane = this.transform.position.z;   // example. use any Z from anywhere here.

// find distance along ray.
float distance = (Zplane-ray.origin.z)/ray.direction.z ;
// that is our point
Vector3 point = ray.origin + ray.direction*distance;
// Z will be equal to Zplane, unless considering rounding errors.
// but can remove that error anyway.
point.z = Zplane;

this.transform.position = point;
```

Could this help? Would work similar with any other plane.

Comment: Yes it helped greatly! Because I was using the X axis I changed the ZPlane into XPlane accordingly. I'll try this code in other angles and see if it works just as well.